# QT Blowfish Charset

Tags: c++, qt, character-encoding, cryptography, blowfish

I need use Blowfish for check password into a database using by CMS.
I work with QBlowfish because I thinking basic class and easy to use but no, I have a problem :

I crypt same string ("**AfuYeew7l**") with same salt ("**$2y$04$pzmGaIWodB/7jTZ8Y.082u**")

When I use *C++*, I have : ("**G?(?"?WIk???*?**")

So when I use *PHP*, I have good hash : ("**$2y$04$pzmGaIWodB/7jTZ8Y.082uA15Z.5VwrLXiBPebxNZ2ET75NqX1QOq**")

My slot who hash :

```
    QByteArray key = NULL;
    QByteArray crypt = NULL;

    QByteArray pass(ui->_Input_Pass_Clair->text().toLocal8Bit()); // Clear Password
    QByteArray hash(ui->_Label_Retour_Hash->text().toLocal8Bit()); // Crypt Password

    key.push_back(ui->_Label_Retour_ID->text().toLocal8Bit()); // SALT
    key.push_back(ui->_Label_Retour_CA->text().toLocal8Bit()); // SALT
    key.push_back(ui->_Label_Retour_SEL->text().toLocal8Bit()); // SALT
    key.push_back("$"); // SALT

    QBlowfish fish(key); 
    fish.setPaddingEnabled(true);

    crypt = fish.encrypted(pass);       
    ui->_Label_Retour_Pass_Crypte->setText(crypt);
```

I think crypt is not on correct formated or also key is not correct formated but I haven't anything idea for correct this

[I join source code if necessary](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49517551/Test_Blowfish.zip)

Comment: Please also show your PHP code.

Comment: You need to implement bcrypt, currently you just have a Blowfish implementation, more information on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28C%29#Blowfish-based_scheme). The format generated by PHP utilizes Base64 encoding, currently you just print out the bytes as if they were part of a textual string.

Comment: Thank @MaartenBodewes for your answer, PHP code is CMS so I test with that : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49517551/password_moodle.php

I enter the full hash saved on BDD in first imput and the clear password on second input, the result show if the strings are equals or not.

If I understand, I need decode my key (salt) before init Blowfish ?

What the difference between BCrypt and Blowfish ? I thinking BCrypt was an upgrade of Blowfish...

Comment: Bcrypt is a Password Based Key Derivation Function or PBKDF. Using a PBKDF is more secure than directly using a hash. Blowfish is the underlying *cryptographic primitive* - Blowfish itself is a block cipher. Blowfish is itself used X times using the salt and password as input. The work factor of Blowfish defines how many times it it used.